# face-detection and tracking with camshift opencv c++ run failed

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans, tracking, face-detection

I'm using Opencv2.4.6 and Netbeans IDE for C++.

I'm trying to do a program to detect a face with the CascadeClassifier, and then pass the Rect of the face to the Camshift function to track this face.

To do that, I took the sample code "Camshiftdemo.cpp" that comes in the samples folder of opencv and I've modified.  In my code instead of use the mouse to select the region over which you want to do tracking, is the cascade classifier which passes that information.

```
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"


#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat image;
int trackObject = 0;
Rect selection;

int main()
{
VideoCapture cap;
Rect trackWindow;
int hsize = 16;
float hranges[] = {0,180};
const float* phranges = hranges;
int matchesNum = 0;

CascadeClassifier cascade;
if (!cascade.load("C:/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")) {
    cout << "Cannot load face xml!" << endl;
    return -1;
}

cap.open("D:/Videos_Proy/ProgramacionII/CAMERA3_clase1.MP4");

if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    cout << "***Could not initialize capturing...***\n";
    return -1;
}

namedWindow( "Result", 1 );

Mat frame, hsv, hue, hist, mask, backproj;

for(;;)
{

    cap >> frame;
    if( frame.empty() )
        break;

    frame.copyTo(image);

    if ( !trackObject )
    {
        Mat grayframe; 
        vector <Rect> facesBuf;
        int detectionsNum = 0;

        cvtColor(image, grayframe, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cascade.detectMultiScale(grayframe, facesBuf, 1.2, 4, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT |
        CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cvSize(0, 0));

        detectionsNum = (int) facesBuf.size();
        Rect *faceRects = &facesBuf[0];

        //It must found faces in three consecutives frames to start the tracking to discard false positives
        if (detectionsNum > 0) 
            matchesNum += 1;
        else matchesNum = 0;
        if ( matchesNum == 3 )
        {
            trackObject = -1;
            selection = faceRects[0];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < detectionsNum; i++) 
        { 
            Rect r = faceRects[i];
            rectangle(image, Point(r.x, r.y), Point(r.x + r.width, r.y + r.height), CV_RGB(0, 255, 0)); 
        }   
    }

    if( trackObject )
    {
        cvtColor(image, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, 69, 53),
                    Scalar(180, 256, 256), mask);
        int ch[] = {0, 0};
        hue.create(hsv.size(), hsv.depth());
        mixChannels(&hsv, 1, &hue, 1, ch, 1);

        if( trackObject < 0 )
        {
            Mat roi(hue, selection), maskroi(mask, selection);
            calcHist(&roi, 1, 0, maskroi, hist, 1, &hsize, &phranges);
            normalize(hist, hist, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX);

            trackWindow = selection;
            trackObject = 1;      
        }

        calcBackProject(&hue, 1, 0, hist, backproj, &phranges);
        backproj &= mask;
        RotatedRect trackBox = CamShift(backproj, trackWindow,
                TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1 ));
        if( trackWindow.area() <= 1 )
        {
            int cols = backproj.cols, rows = backproj.rows, r = (MIN(cols, rows) + 5)/6;
            trackWindow = Rect(trackWindow.x - r, trackWindow.y - r,
                    trackWindow.x + r, trackWindow.y + r) &
                    Rect(0, 0, cols, rows);
        }

        ellipse( image, trackBox, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA );
    }


    imshow( "Result", image );

    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;

}

return 0;
}
```

This code makes sense to me, and when I Build it in Netbeans do not get any error, the problem is that don't run and Netbeans don't give any clue, only says: **RUN FAILED (exit value -1.073.741.819, total time: 5s)**

Anyone could help me and give any idea about what is happening. Thanks!!

Comment: This might be a good time to learn about debugging: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/debugging.html I don't use Netbeans, so I cannot help you with the details...

Comment: Ok, after debug the program I can say that at line (32):  "cap.open (..." the debugger return a Segmentation Fault, but I don't understand why, and for example if I make a comment between the line (103 to 113)"RotatedRect trackBox = CamShift ..."  and  "... , Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA );" the program runs without any problem.

Comment: In a situation like this, it is an indicator that some function writes over some memory boundaries. My guess would be "ellipse", but I have not looked too closely at your source code.